# Android Studio Navigation Drawer item opening website

Tags: java, drawer

I used the basic "Navigation Drawer Acticity" in Anroid Studio when creating the new project. The fragments work well and I've managed to add new fragments and everything.
However, items in the drawer menu that direct you to a certain website don't work. I've tried different methods with public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item){} and nothing happens when I press the items.

It looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        

       if (id == R.id.nav_moodle) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

As you can see I did nothing for the fragments to work since they work fine already but when I press the button "moodle", nothing happens.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: have you implemented setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this) on your navigation view?

Comment: I start the code like this:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Comment: Can you please post the complete code so that I can check. If you haven't implemented setNavigationItemSelectedListener then you need to implement to click on item

Answer (score 0):

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.ustudy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ustudy.ui.home.HomeFragment;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.ustudy.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());




        //required for the top bar to be clickable
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);

        //button in the bottom right corner
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        //Navigationview for the drawer (implemented in "activity_main.xml")
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        //each screen mentioned in the columns below (R.id.xy) will show the hamburger menu in the top left corner
        //on screens, not included in the columns, there will be a "back arrow" instead of the ham. menu
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_nachricht, R.id.nav_lerngruppe, R.id.nav_lehrveranstaltung)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        //controls what happens when one of the items in the hamburger menu is clicked on
        //go to "mobile_navigation.xml" to add screens to go to
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);

        //required to set up the hamburger menu icon and the back-arrow icon on the top bar(without it
        //the user had to slide the side of the screen to open the menu)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);

        //enables the items in the hamburger menu to go to a certain screen after clicking on them
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu (three dots on the right); this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        //enables the usage of the back-arrow on every screen
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull @NotNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_moodle) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please, let me know if you need more!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).